# Access object parameter from a different class?

Tags: c#, class, object

I need to be able to show how many enrolled students there are in each year level. So I have a class called School in which the objects students created in class Students can be enrolled into a specific school, no idea how to do this. Am trying to learn OOP as I didn't do this in Uni and have to teach it. I know it is probably a simple question but have tried all sorts for a week now and just plain confused. Code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace objects2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Student jack = new Student();
        jack.setName("Jack");
        jack.setStudentNumber(1);
        jack.setYearLevel(13);
        Student jane = new Student();
        jane.setName("Jane");
        jane.setStudentNumber(2);
        jane.setYearLevel(10);
        Student Amy = new Student();
        Amy.setName("Amy");
        Amy.setStudentNumber(3);
        Amy.setYearLevel(10);
        Student Ezekeil = new Student();
        Ezekeil.setName("Ezekiel");
        Ezekeil.setStudentNumber(4);
        Ezekeil.setYearLevel(9);
        Student Burt = new Student();
        Burt.setName("Burt");
        Burt.setStudentNumber(5);
        Burt.setYearLevel(9);
        Student Ernie = new Student();
        Ernie.setName("Ernie");
        Ernie.setStudentNumber(6);
        Ernie.setYearLevel(11);
        Student James = new Student();
        James.setName("James");
        James.setStudentNumber(7);
        James.setYearLevel(11);

        School CHBC = new School();
        CHBC.enrol(Amy);
        CHBC.enrol(jack);
        CHBC.enrol(jane);
        CHBC.enrol(Ezekeil);
        CHBC.enrol(Burt);
        CHBC.enrol(Ernie);
        Console.WriteLine(" Number enrolled: " + CHBC.countEnrolled);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Student
{
    private string name;
    private int studentNumber;
    private int yearLevel = 9;

    public int setYearLevel(int yearLevel)
    {
        if (yearLevel <= 13 && yearLevel >= 9)
        {
            //talking about the variable in the class by using this to stop having to reinvent names
            this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
            return 0;
        }
        //error codes so can have specific error otherwise could use boolean for OK or not OK
        return -1;
    }
    public int showYearLevel()
    {
        return yearLevel;
    }
    public void setStudentNumber(int studentNumber)
    {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
    public int showStudentNumber()
    {
        return studentNumber;

    }
    public void setName(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public string showName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

class School
{
    private string schoolName;
    private string type;
    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>;
    private int numberEnrolled;


    public void enrol(Student newStudent)
    {
        //add students to my list as they arre enrolled
        students.Add(newStudent);

    }
    public void setSchoolName(string schoolName)
    {
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }

    public int countEnrolled
    {
        get
        {
            numberEnrolled = students.Count();
            return numberEnrolled;
        }
    }
    public void setType(string type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you writing explicit setters and getters instead of using C# properties?

Answer (score 0):

That `Student` class is horrible. Start with something like this:

```
class Student
{
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int YearLevel { get; private set; }

    const int yearLevelMin = 9;
    const int yearLevelMax = 13;

    public Student(int number, string name, int yearlevel)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        if (yearlevel < yearLevelMin || yearlevel > yearLevelMax)
            throw new StudentException($"{nameof(yearlevel)} must be between {yearLevelMin} and {yearLevelMax}.");

        Number = number;
        Name = name;
        YearLevel = yearlevel;
    }
}
```

Get your basic classes working first. I won't write your `School` class for you, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
var school = new School("Example High")
    .Add(new Student(1, "Jack", 13))
    .Add(new Student(2, "Jane", 10));
```

Comment: Lol that how my instructor showed me, I can see how yours is much neater

Comment: It's not just “neater”; it prevents errors like adding null or invalid students. Your original version has some fundamental flaws.

Comment: Your instructor is probably a java developer, though the names would then have been "getX" and "setX", not "showX". Even if you wanted to stick with the methods I advice you to learn proper naming considerations, the verb "show" implies that something is "shown" which is not what the method does. It doesn't show anything, it *returns* something though, which is usually either named "get" (get the existing X) or "create" (create a new X).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to skip some details and just get straight to answer your question.

First thing first, you need to have a public accessor of your property.

```
public class Student
{
   public int Number { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int YearLevel { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can count the number of Students by year level.

```
// this is using Linq
int numberOfStudents = Students.Count(s=>s.YearLevel == yearLevelYouAreLooking);
```

But you want to show the counts on each year level, so what you need is to group the Students by YearLevel and get the count.

```
 // school is School instance
 var result = from student in school.Students // from all students in the school
              group student by student.YearLevel into g // group the students by the YearLevel
              select new { YearLevel = g.Key, Count = g.Count() } // create a new list of YearLevel and the count.
```

To show the result into the Console

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Number of students of {item.YearLevel} is {item.Count}");
}
```

You can make them as a method of the class as necessary.

**Note:** the result is not in the order. If you need the result to be ordered then add:

```
orderby student.YearLevel // in between "from" and "group", but this is not optimal, because you are re-ordering the input first, which can be large.
```

or

```
orderby g.Key // in between "group" and "select". Since the grouped result will be smaller than the input, ordering is optimal.
```